# Select only rows if the value in a particular set of columns is 'NA' in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with many rows and columns in it (3000x37) and I want to be able to select only rows that may have >= 2 columns of value "NA". These columns have data of different data types. I know how to do this in case I want to select only one column via:

```
df[is.na(df$col.name), ]
```

How to make this selection if I want to select two (or more) columns?

Comment: what about some variant of `if (apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x))) >= *val*) {...}` ?

Comment: you said you wanted to select columns with only greater... actually equal to... 2,3,4, etc `NA`s. val is how many `NA`s

Comment: I meant two (three, four, ...) "corresponding" columns, not data values. I am sorry for my English.

Comment: @FaizLotfy you mean rows that have greater than or equal to 2 NA's, right?

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a vector `nn` with the of the number of NA's in each row and then select only those rows with >= 2 NA's `d[nn>=2,]`

```
d = data.frame(x=c(NA,1,2,3), y=c(NA,"a",NA,"c"))
nn = apply(d, 1, FUN=function (x) {sum(is.na(x))})
d[nn>=2,]

   x    y
1 NA <NA>
```

Comment: `d[rowSums(is.na(d)) >= 2, ]`

Comment: yeah, that is MUCH simpler.

Comment: @FaizLotfy use the code that rawr put in above as a comment. it is much simpler